# Designing a web service to be called by another language

Tags: web-services

This will sound naive (but then I am a junior programmer), but if I write a web service say in Python (standard WSDL web service), I then need to host it so it is reachable from an end point.

This will give a URI for the service and then from another language, say Java or VB.NET (any), I can add a web service (this one) and then call the web service's object model, correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> if I write a web service say in Python (standard WSDL web service), I then need to host it so it is reachable from an end point.

By definition, a web service need to be exposed through HTTP i.e. "hosted" (by the way, WSDL is a language to describe a web service).

> then from another language, say Java or VB.NET (any), I can add a web service (this one) and then call the web service's object model, correct?

Without entering in the details, web services are basically web APIs accessed via HTTP. So yes, you will be able to call a web service from any language than can make HTTP requests (not sure what you mean by "add a web service" though).

If you are expecting a more precise answer, feel free to ask a more precise question :)

Comment: Yes, Web Services are language agnostic, it does not matter what language the service is implemented in, as long as the client supports the same WS spec then you are good to go.